# Authentication via REST in Apache Shiro

Tags: rest, shiro

I would like to enable authentication using a `REST` (preferably POST) call in `Apache Shiro`. The reason I want to use a REST call is so that both a web and mobile app, as well as a 3rd party using my API can use the same authentication call, which if true would pass back 200 and a token, which would then be used as a query (or form) parameter to authenticate the next call.

Can Shiro support the above described model? I am still evaluating Shiro and learning about it.

I have used some other authentication frameworks but they required that their login page in HTML be used to obtain authentication and I didn't like that because it eliminates mobile and 3rd party use.

Answer (score 2):

For third-party API use cases, you probably want to use an OAuth flow:

[Illustrated Guide to OAuth & OIDC](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/21/illustrated-guide-to-oauth-and-oidc)

Shiro can act as the "Resource Server", see:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/05/11/java-shiro-oauth

Full disclosure, I work at Okta, and the above link is Okta specific but you could do [something similar](https://github.com/oktadev/okta-shiro-plugin/blob/401c546822b3ceb385c9090dd78040db838fb84d/core/src/main/java/com/okta/shiro/realm/OktaResourceServerRealm.java#L98-L110) with another IdP like Keycloak.